# expo init AwesomeProject gives the following warning always. Do I have to update it? if yes then how? And what does the warning mean?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

warning expo > fbemitter > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
warning react-native-web > deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.

I tried updating core js with the following command: npm install --save core-js@^3 and got errors. What does core-js here mean?

Comment: Can you try to update the expo-cli: npm install -g expo-cli and run it again.

Comment: I did that and the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to the best of my knowledge, these would be warnings from your global node modules not your local project modules so running `npm install --save core-js@^3` will not do the trick.

Try adding the global flag `-g` so in essence run the following:

```
npm install -g core-js@^3
```